# Windows 10 cumulative update makes UWP application crash when accessing printing window

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Since the [September 12, 2023—KB5030214 (OS Build 17763.4851)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-12-2023-kb5030214-os-build-17763-4851-e6ae7551-49f4-428e-b2d4-caa73078fb06#articleFooterSupportBridge=communityBridge), the printing window makes our UWP app crash.

Our UWP app uses the version 10.0.17134 (Min and Target).

We simply use the following code to print : [microsoft/Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Printing/cs) (PrintManager).

Multiple notes to reproduce :

- The default printer (such as "Microsoft print to pdf") does not make the app crash.
- When switching from any windows default printer) to a **PHYSICAL** printer, the error "Printer encountered a configuration problem 0x8007007a" briefly appears, then the app crashes.
  The code could also be "0x800706be", with the same text message.
- The notepad app seems to use the default printing window, same as the UWP app, but does not crash.
- Uninstalling the package KB5030214 makes everything comes to life again.

The event viewer does not seem to have any useful information, here's a screenshot :
[image]

This problem is similar to [Printing in UWP apps fails with security patch KB5008212](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/863040/printing-in-uwp-apps-fails-with-security-patch-kb5), but with, this time, a different patch.

For the life of me, I cannot post on the Microsoft Learn forums (I get "Post removed because of community guidelines", and now I get "You are not authorized to make this response. If you believe this to be in error, please refresh the page and try again.").

Does anyone has fixed the problem without uninstalling the patch ?

Comment: Please report this issue in the system Feedback Hub app. You could find it in the Start Menu.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT That can't be right. Feedback is used for the average consumer. I am talking about the development side of windows. Plus, the window doesn't let enough characters to write a proper "feedback".

Comment: You could report API related issue as well.  Please select **Developer Platform**-> **API Feedback** as the category when you submit your request.

Comment: I created it here [https://aka.ms/AAmvdrf](https://aka.ms/AAmvdrf). No answers after more than a week and 3000 customers stuck.